# In Spring I Use @Transactional in save methos, throw RollbackException

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I use @Transaction on method like this

```
@Transactional
public void savePerson(Person person){
...
}
```

then throw exception

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException:
```

I use

```
@Transactional(readonly=true)
```

for other method that only fetch data like

```
public Person findPerson(Long personId){...}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? Is it that exception? Can you show more of that stacktrace?

Comment: it throw rollbackexception , I add part of exception to my question, can you see?

Comment: And that's all it says? Usually there's dozens of additional lines that say why the rollback happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem, It was that in my method there is an exception that i think that it was of @Transactional